# GNOME-Boxes vs VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, gnome-boxes

Which would be "faster" more "responsive" virtual machine software? GNOME-Boxes or VirtualBox?

Comment: AFAIK, Gnome Boxes is not a Virtual Machine, but a front end for kvm (and may another VMs) mixed with a remote access client.  For a virtual machine list, please check this question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use). Note that Gnome boxes will perform something similar to virt-manager (the second most voted option)

Comment: What about the features and functionality?

Answer (score 10):

**[GNOME Boxes](http://live.gnome.org/Boxes)** is a graphical user interface similar to virt-manager aimed to access virtual machines based on Qemu or for viewing remote desktops:

> That said, Boxes will be sharing a lot of code-base with virt-manager project, mainly in the form of libvirt, libosinfo (not yet used by virt-manager) and qemu.<sup>GNOME</sup>

Therefore it is not expected that there will be any performance improvements in comparison with existing [virtualization software listed here](https://askubuntu.com/q/41407/3940). It may however be easier to access you virtual machines from GNOME. There is also a [question on this topic here](https://askubuntu.com/q/2353/3940).

From my experience [Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940) is so easy to handle that it does not really need any user interface other than the one provided. It also has the advantage of a being a cross- platform application.

Answer (score 1):

Although speed is a relevant question, I think what would be more important is how it handles processor threads and memory allocation.

I'm newish to Xenserver and definitely no experience with Gnome-Boxes (yet), but I've been using VirtualBox and VMWare for a few years now.  VMWare V-Sphere (I believe this was only available with an Enterprise license) has the nice bonus of being able to throttle up/down processors and cores and dynamic ram allocation - meaning if another VM requires more power or memory, it has the ability of doing so without going below certain thresholds that may impact performance overall.

VirtualBox - does not have this feature from my experience. Granted you can set a "Maximum" throttle for the CPU use, and the amount of virtual cores to use, but I don't believe I've seen settings to dynamically allocate memory (Perhaps the memory allocation is a maximum and it throttles it down/up in the background if needed?)

I'm sure XenServer and the Xen Project have these features built in, but I'd be curious to know how Gnome-Boxes handles it, or if it handles these situations better than VirtualBox. I think I'm going to throw a system together to test this unless someone has this information already :-)

Answer (score -1):

The question is whether Gnome Boxes or VirtualBox will be "faster" or "more responsive"...AFAIK there is too little information available about Gnome Boxes at the moment to draw a conclusion. Keep up with the news and see how Gnome Boxes will shape up.