# Which is the best virtual software for running latest windows program

Tags: software-recommendation, microsoft-office, photoshop, crossplatform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the friendliest virtualization solution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2353/whats-the-friendliest-virtualization-solution)

Which is the best virtual platform should I install to run latest Windows program like MS-Office , Adobe Photoshop cs4, etc. I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on 64 bits core i5 processor?
I need to run these programs on my Ubuntu system without having to install Windows. Downloaded programs such as wine and Play on Linux but it shows error every time I try to run these Windows program as mentioned above. 
Any alternate softwares you can suggest?
Thanks

Comment: Its not the same. Its different with different set of issues. Any help on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install windows in Virtual Box to run those programs.
Virtual Box can be installed from software centre, and is easy to use.

Comment: I just plan to run .exe files not to install the full Windows software? What do I do? thanks

Comment: Windows software works best on windows, but Crossover is the best choice if you don't want to install windows in a VM or otherwise, you can find Crossover in software centre.

Comment: CrossOver causing lot of troubles... not able to install  Play on Linux is now asking to mount from cd-rom which I don't have in my system. How to proceed next? I am trying to install ms-office 2010.

Comment: Installed Virtual Box.. now everything works fine as desired. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, glad everything's working ok :o)